# Viewpager Vertical

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to make default viewpager use vertical scrolling. And I'm stuck. I tried using [Directional ViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager)
but it's kinda buggy and very laggy with vertical ori

Then i tried [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager) but i don't know how to use that. Replacing normal viewpager doesn't work. Any ideas how to implement Vertical View pager?

Edit: I also tried [vertical view pager](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager) but this one working only in Android Studio, dunno how to use it in Eclipse, should i import project as a lib? or compile it to jar file and import as a lib?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical ViewPager implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889530/vertical-viewpager-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of the compatibility library ViewPager class that supports paging both vertically and horizontally.

but you can choose to use a lib

[Android-DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/)

For a working implementation of this project see the sample/ folder.

Include the widget in your view.

```
<com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

By default the widget will page horizontally. You can alter this behavior by including android:orientation="vertical" in the layout or by calling setOrientation(DirectionalViewPager.VERTICAL) in your code.

In your onCreate method (or onCreateView for a fragment), bind to a PagerAdapter implementation.

```
 DirectionalViewPager pager = (DirectionalViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

[ViewPager-Android](https://github.com/rharter/ViewPager-Android)

ViewPager, Based on the Android support library's ViewPager class, this ViewPager supports both horizontal and vertical paging views.

This ViewPager is a drop in replacement for the support library version. Simply reference the library and replace your ViewPager imports with this version.

Reference in your XML like this.

```
<com.ryanharter.viewpager.ViewPager
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Notice that you can use `app:orientation="vertical"` to easily set the orientation of the ViewPager to vertical. Orientation defaults to horizontal.

You can also set orientation in code using

```
mViewPager.setOrientation(ViewPager.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL).
```

Comment: That lib is deprecated and not working properly. It uses old version of support lib and replacing to new one causes to many problems.